# disabling gzip when etag returned from upstream used

Tags: nginx, gzip, etag

Following this ticket:
http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/377

gzip removes etag headers.

Is there a way to check if upstream returned the ETag header and if it did to disable gzip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

the issue was resolved here:
trac.nginx.org/nginx/changeset/e491b26fa5a1908eb22dd96d19b4d26e25eeca2c/nginx